# How to use rspec_scaffold generator with latest rspec gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I am a newbie to Rails 3 and Rspec. Kindly excuse my being a novice.

I am trying to use RSpec with Rails 3. I am using rails 3.0.3 and ruby 1.9.2 on ubuntu 10.04 os.

I am currently referring to the tutorial on :- http://www.railsfire.com/article/rspec-behaviour-driven-development-testing-framework. This tutorial not only uses old plugins , but old Rails version of 2.x also.

I am unable to use the old rspec generator ( rspec_scaffold ) with rspec 2.5 and rspec-rails 2.5 gem. As expected I get the following error as given below.

```
mohnish@mohnish-desktop:~/rails_testing/10Mar11/rspec_demo3$ rails g rspec_scaffold post title:string body:text
Could not find generator rspec_scaffold.
mohnish@mohnish-desktop:~/rails_testing/10Mar11/rspec_demo3$
```

Could you please tell me how should I give to accordingly for it to work for me using the above RoR configuration.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest Rspec gems don't require the old generator mentioned above, basically on giving `rails` g in your rails app you would get all the list of generators with your app.

Thus, once you have installed the Rspec related gems, then give a rails g to your app, you need to basically run only one of the generator command from the modified list that you would get, which is `rspec:install` and this would be enough to get you up & running at least with a proof of concept(poc).